# How can I override await() method of CountDownLatch in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently working on a task where I have to stop a multi-threaded process if the client requests to.
I was thinking to take a static variable flag and initialise it to false that could be constantly checked from time to time, if it becomes true we can stop the execution of the threads.

One of the approaches I am seeking is if I could override the await() method of CountDownLatch or awaitTermination() method of ExecutorService class.
The overridden method will check if the flag is not true, then it would call the method of the base class, else I could call shutDownNow().

Somewhat like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = 
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS_COUNT);
CountDownLatch tasksLeft = new CountDownLatch(THREADS_COUNT);

while(i++ < processCount) {
    RandomProcessThread thread = new RandomProcessThread(i, someParams);
    executorService.submit();
}

tasksLeft.await();
if(shutDownFlagTrue) {
    executorService.shutDownNow();
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void await() throws InterruptedException {
    if(hasClientRequestedToStop)
        shutDownFlagTrue = true;
    else
        this.await();
}
```

---

Any other inputs on how to implement this are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not the proper way of doing. ExecutrService.submit() returns a Future. Future has a cancel() method, which can optionally interrupt the thread if the task is executing. And the task can periodically check if the current thread is interrupted to stop running ASAP. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: Thank you. I will go through this.Also I was thinking if I could write an empty return statement (return;) in the run method of the thread, if the condition comes true. Is that the wrong way to do?